# CSS: Invisible element with transition: all flashes on page load

Tags: html, css

I have a popup element which is hidden by default and only shows up programmatically when the script assigns a specific class to its container and populates the popup text.

In `css/stylesheet.css`:

```
.error-message {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.container.with-error .error-message {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

In `index.html`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
<div class="container">
    <div class="error-message">This text will be changed by a script.</div>
</div>
```

According to this simple style declaration, the `.error-message` element should always be invisible, unless it is preceded by a `.container.with-error`, in which case it becomes visible, and its appearance is always animated because of `transition` property.

However, the `.error-message` triggers its transition when the page is loaded, resulting in a flash which I believe it should not do.

Related behavior I have observed:

- The flash does not appear if the style is declared in an inline `<style>` tag
- The flash appears if every style but `transition: all` is declared in an inline `<style>` tag
- The flash does not appear if the style is loaded from a Base-64 encoded Data URL like this: `<link href="data:text/css;base64,...">`
- The flash does not appear if the style loaded from `<link rel="stylesheet">` is retrieved from cache.

I've created a demo that reproduces this bug every time. To simulate requesting a remote stylesheet without cache, a `blob://` Object URL is generated from the style instead. The inline demo is available at the end of this question, but for best results, use [JSBin](https://output.jsbin.com/yuronelacu). Use <kbd>F5</kbd> to see the bug in action.

I'm curious how to fix this and what causes this issue as this is clearly not intended behavior.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script>
            /* jshint browser: true, esversion: 6 */

            window.onload = function() {

                // Log all transition events
                window.ontransitioncancel = appendToTransitionLog;
                window.ontransitionstart = appendToTransitionLog;
                window.ontransitionrun = appendToTransitionLog;
                window.ontransitionend = appendToTransitionLog;

                // Simulates loading a stylesheet from a remote location
                // Works the same way as if #simulated-stylesheet's content
                // was hosted and served from <link rel=stylesheet> without cache
                //
                // Keep in mind that this bug does not appear
                // if the style is injected or loaded from cache!
                createFakeStylesheet();
            };
            
            function createFakeStylesheet() {
                var styleContent = document.getElementById("simulated-stylesheet").text;
                var styleBlob = new Blob([styleContent], {type: "text/css"});
                var styleURL = URL.createObjectURL(styleBlob);

                var linkElement = document.createElement("link");
                linkElement.rel = "stylesheet";
                linkElement.href = styleURL;

                document.head.appendChild(linkElement);
            }

            // Functions below handle transition events logging

            // Template import helper
            function importTemplateFromId(id) {
                return document.importNode(document.getElementById(id).content, true);
            }

            // Returns a string like "div.class1.class2" to describe an element
            function describeElement(element) {
                var tagName = element.tagName.toLowerCase();
                var classes = element.classList.toString().split(" ").filter(className => className != "").map(className => "." + className).join("");
                return tagName + classes;
            }

            // Returns a matching log group wrapper.
            // The wrapper is created if the group does not exists.
            // Used for grouping transition events by element descriptor
            function getLogWrapper(logContainer, elementText) {
                var matchingWrapper = logContainer.querySelector(".wrapper[data-for-element=\"" + elementText + "\"] .logs");

                if (matchingWrapper) {
                    return matchingWrapper;
                }

                var wrapperTemplate = importTemplateFromId("wrapper-template");
                var wrapperName = wrapperTemplate.querySelector(".name");
                var wrapperElement = wrapperTemplate.querySelector(".wrapper");
                wrapperName.textContent = elementText;
                wrapperElement.dataset.forElement = elementText;

                return logContainer.appendChild(wrapperElement).querySelector(".logs");
            }

            // Logs a transition event.
            // Logs are grouped by each event type (start, run, end)
            // and target element's descriptor (see describeElement)
            function appendToTransitionLog(transitionEvent) {
                var eventType = transitionEvent.type;

                var eventProperty = transitionEvent.propertyName;

                var logContainer = document.getElementById("log-" + eventType);
                var elementText = describeElement(transitionEvent.target);
                var logWrapper = getLogWrapper(logContainer, elementText);

                var logEntry = document.createElement("span");
                logEntry.textContent = eventProperty;
                logEntry.className = "entry";
                logWrapper.appendChild(logEntry);
            }
        </script>

        <style>
            #edit-with-js-bin {
                display: none!important;
            }
            
            .log {
                font-size: 14px;
            }

            .log .wrapper {
                padding-left: 16px;
            }

            .wrapper .name {
                text-decoration: underline;
            }

            .wrapper .logs {
                padding-left: 12px;
            }

            .wrapper .entry {
                display: inline-block;
                color: grey;
                padding: 8px 4px;
            }

            .wrapper .entry:nth-child(2n) {
                color: lightgrey;
            }

            body {
                font-family: monospace;
                font-size: 0;
            }

            .side {
                display: inline-block;
                font-size: 14px;
                vertical-align: top;
                width: 50%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>

        <template id="wrapper-template">
            <div class="wrapper" data-for>
                <span class="name"></span>
                <div class="logs"></div>
            </div>
        </template>

        <script id="simulated-stylesheet" type="text/css">
            .remote {
                background: crimson;
                color: white;
                display: inline-block;
                margin: 8px;
                padding: 8px;
            }

            .remote.transparent {
                opacity: 0;
                visibility: hidden;
            }

            .remote.transition-some {
                transition: opacity, visibility 1s ease;
            }

            .remote.transition-all {
                transition: all 1s ease;
            }
        </script>

        <style>
            .transition-all-inline {
                transition: all 1s ease;
            }

            .local {
                background: green;
                color: white;
                display: inline-block;
                margin: 8px;
                padding: 8px;
            }

            .local.transparent {
                opacity: 0;
                visibility: hidden;
            }

            .local.transition-some {
                transition: opacity, visibility 1s ease;
            }

            .local.transition-all {
                transition: all 1s ease;
            }

            .mock {
                background: orangered;
                transition: all 1s ease;
            }
            .mock:hover {
                background: orange;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="side left">
            <div>
                <u>.remote</u> <div class="remote">I'm always styled.</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                .remote<u>.transparent</u> <div class="remote transparent">I'm always transparent.</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                .remote.transparent<u>.transition-some</u> <div class="remote transparent transition-some">I'm invisible!</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                .remote.transparent<u>.transition-all</u> <div class="remote transparent transition-all">I will briefly flash when the page loads.</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                .remote.transparent<u>.transition-all-inline</u> <div class="remote transparent transition-all-inline">I will briefly flash when the page loads.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="side right">
            <div>
                <u>.local</u> <div class="local">I'm always styled.</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                .local<u>.transparent</u> <div class="local transparent">I'm always transparent.</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                .local.transparent<u>.transition-some</u> <div class="local transparent transition-some">I'm invisible!</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                .local.transparent<u>.transition-all</u> <div class="local transparent transition-all">I'm invisible!</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                .local.transparent<u>.transition-all-inline</u> <div class="local transparent transition-all-inline">I'm invisible!</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                .local.mock <div class="local mock">Use me to debug transition events!</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="log">
            <div>
                <b>ontransitionstart</b>
                <div id="log-transitionstart"></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <b>ontransitionrun</b>
                <div id="log-transitionrun"></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <b>ontransitionend</b>
                <div id="log-transitionend"></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <b>ontransitioncancel</b>
                <div id="log-ontransitioncancel"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

**EDIT:** The flash appears regardless of what property is being transitioned.

This still creates the same effect:

```
.error-message {
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
}
```

Comment: It's a Chromium bug. Firefox handles it correctly. For now you'll have to live without the `all` property.

Comment: @user8977154 I'm getting the same issue on the latest version of Firefox -- check JSBin for a reproducible test case.

Comment: @Kaiido The problem is the flash occurs without any Javascript interaction, by just having this element present on page it triggers its transition.

Comment: @user8977154 I've verified it and the flash still occurs regardless of what property transition is applied to, even if it's `opacity` instead of `all`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a normal behavior of transition (not a bug of any specific browser).

The issue in your case is that you **already have elements** (that flashes) in the DOM tree.
That also means the elements have an initial state and any new state performs a transition. If a new style applied and it has a `transition` property a browser will show you animation between the initial state and the new state with a transition property. (*Note that the initial state of the element that flashes is not transparent*).

The possible fix for that is to add *hidden* elements when new styles already exist. Or refactor your styles to have a transparent initial state.